# I would like to set a limit to a double variable

Tags: java, double, limit

This part of the program is for calculating how long it takes to face a part. 
It starts with some basic info, work piece diameter, feed rate and surface speed you want to tool to operate at. Then it runs a while loop, each time the tool advances 0.010", it calculates the new rpm the piece will rotate at and calculates the time for that cut adding it all up at the end.

The problem: I need to be able to limit the rpms. As the tool gets closer to the center of the work piece the rpms will climb to a very high unattainable rpm, I want to be able to set a limit, 2000 for example.

I cannot figure out how to do that with out affecting my loop... I have searched, but I'm such a noob maybe I've stumbled across a solution that would work and never realized it, or I am not searching for the correct key words. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double startRadius = 6; //Radius of stock diameter
    double faceFinish = 0; 
    double feed = .010; //Amount the tool will advance per revolution
    double sfm = 200; //Surface speed of tool (Surface feet per minute)
    double rpm = 0;
    double totalTime = 0;

    while(faceFinish < startRadius) {
        startRadius -= feed; //reduces diameter by feed
        rpm = (sfm * 3.82) / (startRadius * 2); //establishes new rpm per tool advance            
        totalTime += (feed / (feed * rpm)) * 60;
    }
    int hours = (int) (totalTime / 3600);
    int minutes = (int) ((totalTime % 3600) / 60);
    int seconds = (int) (totalTime % 60);
    System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Edit - If/else which seems to be working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double startRadius = 6;
    double faceFinish = 0;
    double feed = .010;
    double sfm = 200;
    double rpm = 0;
    double rpm2 = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double total2 = 0;
    double totalTime = 0;

    while(faceFinish < startRadius) {
        startRadius -= feed; 
        rpm = (sfm * 3.82) / (startRadius * 2);             
        if(rpm > 2000) {
            rpm = 2000;
            total += (feed / (feed * rpm)) * 60;
        }else {
            total2 += (feed / (feed * rpm)) * 60;
        }
    totalTime = total + total2;

    }
    int hours = (int) (totalTime / 3600);
    int minutes = (int) ((totalTime % 3600) / 60);
    int seconds = (int) (totalTime % 60);
    System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? And why has it failed?

Comment: Good morning Joe,
I was originally using an if else statement for two rpm conditions and adding them together at the end. It wasn't giving me a correct outcome until this morning when I typed up a response I realized where I went wrong. I was trying to use two individual rpm variables vs reusing the one. It is now giving me the same result as Shivams proposed code. 
I updated my op with how I was trying to do it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try below code.

```
class Rpm{
    double value=0.0;
    final double LIMIT = 2000.0;
    public void setValue(double value){
        if(value < LIMIT)
            this.value= value;

    }
    public double getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}

public class  yourclassname {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double startRadius = 6; //Radius of stock diameter
    double faceFinish = 0; 
    double feed = .010; //Amount the tool will advance per revolution
    double sfm = 200; //Surface speed of tool (Surface feet per minute)
    Rpm rpm = new Rpm();
    double totalTime = 0;

    while(faceFinish < startRadius) {
        startRadius -= feed; //reduces diameter by feed
        rpm.setValue( (sfm * 3.82) / (startRadius * 2)); //establishes new rpm per tool advance            
        totalTime += (feed / (feed * rpm.getValue())) * 60;
    }
    int hours = (int) (totalTime / 3600);
    int minutes = (int) ((totalTime % 3600) / 60);
    int seconds = (int) (totalTime % 60);
    System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", hours, minutes, seconds);
}
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a code-writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to post that however, thanks for the responses.

Comment: Shivam, this is what I had in my mind when I was searching for solutions. I just wasn't sure how to go about doing it or how to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code snippet for the while loop you are using

```
    while(faceFinish < startRadius) {
    startRadius -= feed; //reduces diameter by feed
    rpm = ((sfm * 3.82) / (startRadius * 2))>2000?2000:((sfm * 3.82) / (startRadius * 2));
    totalTime += (feed / (feed * rpm)) * 60;
}
```